# Unable to install mbstring on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, apache2, php

I am installing mbstring on ubuntu 16.04 which is required for laravel 8. The following error occurred.

```
root@localhost:~# sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-mbstring : Depends: libonig2 (>= 5.9.5) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Unless you have specifically installed PHP 7.4 on that machine, your version of PHP is not compatible with that package. Run `php --version` from the command line to see which version you have. It *may* still be available as `php-mbstring`, but 16.04 is very close to EOL.

Comment: run php --version gives php 7.4. I also tried to install ``sudo apt-get install php-mbstring``

Comment: This is the output https://prnt.sc/xd7ujg

Comment: This version of Ubuntu is also end of life in April. Time for an upgrade.

Comment: @David I will try latest Ubuntu